# Destroy session from python, executing a php script

Tags: php, python, session

I created a python script for managing a multi tenant system on my server. The goal is to log out user sessions through the same script in python, executing a PHP script like this:

**log_out_users.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

session_unset();

session_destroy();

?>
```

with this Python code:

```
import subprocess

command = "php /var/www/tenant/log_out_users.php"
subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

The script runs correctly, but the session is not destroyed. It doesn't even work if I call the php file from CLI, entering into the tenant folder and running the command

`php log_out_users.php`

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by denying access to users via .htaccess, in [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html) way.